# .htaccess redirect loop - root URL duplicate

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to achieve the following with .htaccess:

- domain.tld/ displays the content originally at domain.tld/home/
- if you visit domain.tld/home/, you are redirected to domain.tld/ (to avoid duplicate content)

I tried the following, but it resulted in an infinite loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/home/$ /
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+home/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [L]
```

Based on: [How to avoid duplicate content mapping urls with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247557/how-to-avoid-duplicate-content-mapping-urls-with-htaccess)